# VBA Code to keep original formatting from file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

How can I keep the formatting from the file `MyWB` that the macro is pulling from? I added `.Value` and it pulls over the data, just not the color/font. I have column A in the workbook conditionally formatted for colors and in *Wingdings* font.

```
Sub Merge_Files_4P()

Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(2).Cells(1).Range
Dim MyExcel As Excel.Application
Dim MyWB As Excel.Workbook
Set MyExcel = New Excel.Application
Set MyWB = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dani7844\Desktop\Copy of Strategic Programs Roadmap.xlsm")

For i = 1 To 6
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(2).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i).Value
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(3).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i).Value
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(4).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, i).Value
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(5).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, i).Value
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(6).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, i).Value
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(7).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).Value
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(8).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, i).Value
Next i

MyWB.Close False
Set MyExcel = Nothing
Set MyWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to retrieve the Excel conditional formatting color and font  and assign it in each of your ranges in Word. AFAIK, there is no direct copy-paste method for this.

Comment: @Daniel Strong: can't you just copy paste the formatting for the cells you want in your loop? Or even, copy paste All?

Comment: @L42 I dont know how to do that. I used the code I put in my excel macro and changed the ranges, but I have never done vba in word so its not working with the table. any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The default property that is used for a range object when using it in a `x = y` operation is its `Value`. That is why you only get the value, and not all (formatting, conditional formatting etc.). You should replace these lines:

```
ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(2).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i).Value
```

with the `Copy` method of range objects, i.e.:

```
MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i).Copy destination:= ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(2).Cells(i).Range
```

Find more about the [Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff837760.aspx) method in the official documentation.

Comment: @ Matteo NNZ when I try your solution I get error: copy method of range class failed.